# Why I can't link the CSS file even when I run code from Wiki page for Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, href

I came across a problem when I tested the example code on wiki page of [Bootstrap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_(front-end_framework)).

[image]

As you can see:

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

the link doesn't have `http:` or `https:`. Someone told me it meant this link could be applied by both these two protocols. However, my testing results showed that it doesn't work!
[image]
Only when I add the `http:` then it works!
[image]

So I am confused now. Does it mean the usage in the wiki page for bootstrap is wrong? Or am I getting something wrong?

Comment: show a fiddle or something, it should work either way

Comment: @chiliNUT I just created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chenhaoyu/EmQXT/). You are right, it works in both way. However, I copied the code and ran the same code locally. It doesn't work!

Comment: because the fiddle is being served over `http`, so the bootstrap URL also uses `http`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code does work - it will request the bootstrap CSS using the same protocol that the calling HTML page uses. How are you running the HTML file you have created?

If you're just opening the page from your computer (ie. not running it from a server), your page will have no protocol itself (no `http` or `https`) so therefore it cannot use the same protocol when trying to render the bootstrap CSS.

Comment: I just copied the code, created a test html file and then ran the code.

Comment: sorry, what do you mean that the page don't have protocol itself?

Comment: look at the URL when you open your test HTML file - it will start with `file://` instead of `http://`. So it will be trying to render the bootstrap CSS using `file://`.

Comment: Does it mean if this code is run on server side and it would work well? However, if I want to run it locally, how can I eliminate this problem?

Comment: specify a protocol, or access your test page via a web server.

Comment: But I just have my own computer, how can I access it via a web server?

Comment: run one on your computer.

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not you need the http will depend on if you have the stylesheets loaded onto your website or in your local directory. If you have it locally installed, then I would modify the stylesheet link to something like the below.

```
<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I think that the bootstrap.min.css is already part of the bootstrap download so you just need to make sure that the stylesheet link is following the right path to wherever it is saved.